# jquery slider with url changer

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change URL in browser without navigating away from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560617/how-to-change-url-in-browser-without-navigating-away-from-page)

I have seen some sites where you click on the next page, and the old page slides out, and the new page slides in, and the url also changes. I was just wondering how this is done. I can give you an example of a site that does it, but not sure I can post urls here.

Comment: There are tons of questions like this. What's your interest is `HASH` or better: `How to change the URI Hash ... `

Comment: Questions similar to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939041/change-hash-without-reload-in-jquery) should give you a good start

Comment: So it just changes a hash tag, e.g. mysite.com/page#new-tag?
What if I wanted it to change the url, to mysite.com/page2?

Comment: Is it possible that after the first try on Google (change URL without navigating to new page) I got this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560617/how-to-change-url-in-browser-without-navigating-away-from-page ?